# Getting QtWebKit working in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtwebkit

I have installed the Qt SDK and I am trying to make a basic web browser using their supposed QtWebKit though it's not in the include list and I am not sure how to include the relevant header/includes to get this show on the road?

Build error: "Cannot open include file: 'QtWebKit': No such file or directory".

Sorry if this is a basic question but I don't have much experience with C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, webkit is not included.

If using qmake, you should add this line to the .pro file.

```
QT += network webkit
```

Comment: Added that to the pro and ran qmake from inside the QCreator and got this error?

error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit

Comment: Can you open the example 'fancy browser', build and run it? Which Qt SDK did you use?

Comment: My project has `QT += network webkit` but I get the same error. The error happens with the fancy browser example as well. Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried the wolfenqt example from the Qt's gitorious repo, and I'm getting a similar error: `'QGraphicsWebView': No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone using Qt 5 or recently releases. This has slightly changed.

You now need to add `webkitwidgets` to your .pro file. Here's what mine looks like

```
QT += core gui webkitwidgets
```